# How do I install a system-wide SSL certificate on openSUSE?

Tags: opensuse, suse, ssl, certificates

I have a PEM certificate that I just downloaded from a webserver. I want to install it system-wide so I can curl the server without it complaining about a missing certificate.

I tried putting the file in /etc/ssl/certs, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As already mentioned SUSE supports [ca-certificates](http://software.opensuse.org/package/ca-certificates) starting with openSUSE 13.1 / SLES 12.

The difference to debian/Ubuntu is the directory for your certififcates. The SLES man page to `update-ca-certificates` has these directories:

```
FILES
   /usr/share/pki/trust/anchors
          Directory of CA certificate trust anchors.

   /usr/share/pki/trust/blacklist
          Directory of blacklisted CA certificates

   /etc/pki/trust/anchors
          Directory of CA certificate trust anchors for use by the admin

   /etc/pki/trust/blacklist
          Directory of blacklisted CA certificates for use by the admin
```

The [openSUSE package mentions](https://github.com/openSUSE/ca-certificates) these:

```
- Packages are expected to install their CA certificates in 
  /usr/share/pki/trust/anchors or /usr/share/pki/trust (no extra subdir) instead
  of /usr/share/ca-certificates/<vendor> now. The anchors subdirectory is for
  regular pem files, the directory one above for pem files in
  openssl's 'trusted' format.
```

Comment: Then run `sudo update-ca-certificates` afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

I would take a look for a package called `ca-certificates` (that's the name it goes by on Red Hat distros). All of the main distros bundle certificates and they're generally in the same location.

Since SuSE uses RPM packages as well I'd guess you could do a query like this to find the name of the package that provides certificates:

```
$ rpm -aq | grep -i cert
ca-certificates-2010.63-3.el6_1.5.noarch
```

With the name of this package I can then `rpm -qi <package name>` to find out more info about it:

```
$ rpm -qi ca-certificates-2010.63-3.el6_1.5.noarch
Name        : ca-certificates              Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 2010.63                           Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 3.el6_1.5                     Build Date: Fri 23 Sep 2011 03:39:46 PM EDT
Install Date: Sat 15 Dec 2012 02:34:14 PM EST      Build Host: c6b5.bsys.dev.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Base       Source RPM: ca-certificates-2010.63-3.el6_1.5.src.rpm
Size        : 1353134                          License: Public Domain
Signature   : RSA/SHA1, Mon 26 Sep 2011 12:17:03 AM EDT, Key ID 0946fca2c105b9de
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
URL         : http://www.mozilla.org/
Summary     : The Mozilla CA root certificate bundle
Description :
This package contains the set of CA certificates chosen by the
Mozilla Foundation for use with the Internet PKI.
```

This command will list its contents:

```
$ rpm -ql ca-certificates-2010.63-3.el6_1.5.noarch
/etc/pki/java
/etc/pki/java/cacerts
/etc/pki/tls
/etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
/etc/pki/tls/certs
/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt
/etc/ssl
/etc/ssl/certs
```

This last command will show you where the certificates are getting stored.

#### YaST

If you don't want to manually do this I believe you can use YaST to add CA certificates as well. Here's a tutorial titled: [Chapter 15. Managing X.509 Certification](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/security/html/book.security/cha.security.yast_ca.html) that should guide you through that process.

Comment: The listed package search command only searches installed packages, not available (SUSE users will have better luck using `zypper -n search cert` to find packages).  And listing the contents of the package does not tell you what the directories the package creates are _for_, just that they exist.  The documentation linked to, when it existed (I'll fix the link in a sec), provides instructions on how to create a new CA, not manage imported CAs.  All that said, this is not really a "bad" answer, as it provides good "how I'd figure this out" steps; it just does not belong as the top answer.

Answer (score 1):

I installed:

```
ca-certificates-cacert
ca-certificates-mozilla
```

and it solved the issue.

Comment: `ca-certficates-mozilla` should be `ca-certificates-mozilla`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `update-ca-certificates` provided by ca-certificates, try these ubuntu instructions and update this answer if required

https://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu

Comment: On openSUSE you should copy to `/usr/share/ca-certificates` instead of `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`.

Comment: On OpenSUSE Leap 42.1 I've found: `/usr/lib/ca-certificates`

Comment: See the answer @Christian posted for the current appropriate directory (`/usr/share/pki/trust/anchors`).